# How to get the aggregation statistics of duplicated rows of pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

How to get the mean of duplicated rows of some columns from another column?

## Setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0,0,1,1,0,1],
                   'B': [0,0,1,1,0,1],
                   'C': [0,1,0,1,0,1],
                   'unused': [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.5],
                   'price': [5,10,50,100,10,200]
                   })

print(df)
```

## Required output

```
   A  B  C  unused  price ABC_mean
0  0  0  0     0.1      5 7.5
1  0  0  1     0.2     10 10
2  1  1  0     0.3     50 50
3  1  1  1     0.4    100 150
4  0  0  0     0.5     10 7.5
5  1  1  1     0.5    200 150
```

Comment: Where does your code fail? You get back the correct column, just assign it to a column of the dataframe via `df['mean'] = df.groupby(['A','B'])['price'].transform('mean')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use groupby:

```
df.groupby(['A','B','C'])['price'].transform('mean')
```

Comment: If A and B would be fixed to be the same, I guess they would not both be required in the dataframe. So I would bet that this does not generalize well to the actual application.